# How to install scientific python packages without new software (Python 2.7.6, Windows 10 64-bit)?

Tags: python, windows

I have Python 2.7.6 installed on Windows 10 (64-bit), and I'd like to add in scientific python packages (scipy, astropy, numpy, etc) without installing more software (Anaconda/Canopy).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you can, you should upgrade to a newer python - 2.7.6 was released over 3 years ago.  The latest 2.7 is 2.7.13 ( https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/ ).

Comment: If you are going to upgrade, I'd recommend to move to Python 3(.6) instead of 2. But I assume the OP just has an old/pre-installed Python running on their machine, and doesn't really want to add or change too much.

Comment: If you have to ask you'll probably find it rather difficult. Anaconda is still probably the easiest way, and you don't need the full Anaconda distribution for that. You can start with miniconda which barely installs anything, and from there only install exactly the packages you need.

Comment: Good point cco, I upgraded to 2.7.13.  Evert, I may even upgrade to 3 sometime, but for now I need to use 2.7 for compatibility with the courses I'm taking.  It really depends on what my future classes ask for, but I suspect in the end I'll end up learning both anyway.  Does it work better with Python 3?

Comment: About Python 3: it is not necessarily easier to install things, but purely for Python itself, improvements will only show up in Python 3. And in 2020, official support for Python 2 stops, and libraries like numpy, scipy & astropy may stop support for Python 2 by then as well (it will all continue to function quite a while after 2020, but still). It seems slightly unfortunate that your courses still use Python 2, as that isn't the future (though learning Python 3 after learning 2 isn't a problem).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Try the binaries on this web site.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pip` may very well work. Though there is a chance you run into missing library dependencies (mostly for scipy); that is what Anaconda & friends try to take care of.

Comment: This is true.  I did some more reading on the topic and learned that with scientific packages, it is much easier to just use a virtual environment to run them and not to try to install them system-wide.  Disappointing, but it does explain all the dead ends and obstacles I seem to be hitting.

Comment: @TaraS A virtual environment doesn't solve things per se; it just means you avoid superuser/administrator access (though pip has a `--user` option, which installs things "user-wide"); and it makes it easy to completely remove a botched setup, as well as handle multiple different setups next to each other (but the average user likely doesn't that).

Comment: @TaraS A virtual environment also doesn't help with library dependencies. This is why software like Conda was created: it is a virtual environment for a bit more than just Python libraries, as it may also install C/C++/etc libraries. One step further and you'd be using Docker apps, and after that probably a virtual machine or a bootable CD. But Conda is usually good enough (fwiw: I don't use Conda nor a virtual environment, and that works fine for me; it just means installing stuff at system level).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input.  I ended up downloading Python 3.6, and the Anaconda3 software as well.  I'm not going to try to install things like Python system-wide until I'm more schooled in the inner workings of my PC.  So far it's all working great.